# UI in Windows Server 2016 to change network type from Public to Private?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2016

Where is the UI to change the *"network type"* from **Public** to **Private** on Windows Server 2016?

- There were user interfaces to do it in earlier versions of Windows, earlier versions of Windows Server, and possibly in later versions of Windows and Windows Server.

I'm asking about Windows Server 2016.

- I'm certain there are group policies, command line options, registry options, powershell options to do it in Windows Server 2016

I'm asking about the GUI to do it.

Answer (score 0):

### Short Version

Go to <kbd>This PC</kbd> → <kbd>Network</kbd>. In an effort to help you turn on Network Discovery, Windows will offer to change the Network Type to **Private** *(as opposed to simply turning on **Network Discovery**)*.

### Long Version

**Step 1 - Turn off Network discovery** *(if it is on)*

- From the **Start** button, search for **Control Panel**
- Go to **Control Panel** → **Network and Internet** → **Network Sharing Center**
- In the left pane click **Advanced Sharing Settings**
- Under **Private** → **Network Discovery** select **Turn off network discovery**
- Click [image]**Save Changes**

Step 2 - Use the fact that **Network Discovery** is off to trick Windows into offering the UI to change the network type to **Private**

- Open **Windows Explorer**
- Navigate to **This PC** → **Network**
- Because Network Discovery is currently off, Windows will offer a UI to let to change the network type to **Private** (in order to enable Network Discovery without enabling Network Discovery)

This may work in other versions or editions of Windows, both past and present. I can't speak to those. This question is only about Windows Server 2016.